# How to launch root activity(Restart Application) using home key in Android?

Tags: android, android-manifest, homescreen

I want to launch the root activity once app is maximized using home key(Previously it is minimized using home key).

I've tried to set `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` on my root activity(Splash) but its not working..

Also tried  `android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"` on all other activity but it 
doesn't work either.

**Example**

*Total i have 5 Activities in the Sequence A,B,C,D,E. I am in D Activity, when i press home key app would be minimized when i again (long press home key) it would open my app but it should begin with Activity A instead of D.*

Any **help/ideas/suggestion** would be appreciated.

Comment: "I want to launch the root activity once app is maximized using home key", do you mean launch from recents? (long press home key)

Comment: Let me give you an example. Total i have 5 Activities in the Sequence A,B,C,D,E. I am in D Activity, when i press home key app would be minimized when i again (long press home key) it would open my app but it should begin with Activity A instead of D. Hope you got the point..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems the `excludeFromRecents` is only true for the root activity. So if you set the `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in your root activity, then your app will not show in the Recents (long press Home key). You can set `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` in your root activity then every time your app is relaunch, it will start from the root activity.

Comment: In all the activities except on root activity??

Comment: Yes in all activities except root activity.

Comment: Do you still get D to show up? Clear the Recents and try again.

Comment: See my edited answer above. I try to check for the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY but it does not show up either.

Comment: so i set only `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` on root activity??

Comment: I've set `clearTaskonLaunch` on root and `excludeFromRecents` in all other activities but its not working..

Comment: No clearTaskOnLaunch and also exludeFromRecents in root activity. You will not see your app from long press home key.

Comment: Why long press doesn't show the app??. If i open the app from the list of apps, it just stucks to the splash screen(root activity) it doesn't move either..

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't move either"? If you want to resume your app from where you last press the home key then remove clearTaskOnLaunch

Comment: Root activity is splash one, it moves to another Activity after 3 seconds, but once i relaunch the app it never moves to another activity, it just sticks to the same activity.

Comment: Just remove all the flags and press home key as soon as the Splash screen come up and then relaunch to see if it got stuck. If it is then something is wrong with your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31638/discussion-between-droid-dev-and-hoan-nguyen)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. Its working and moving to another activity once i removed all the flags..